# New Vegas Companions Quests

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Are Companion Quest in New Vegas necessary to complete ?

Are there any penalties if I don't complete all of them ?

Comment: Someone down-voted this without explaining the problem. If you're still reading this, please explain why this is a bad question. Until then I've up-voted to compensate since this seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of your companions' quests are necessary to complete any of the main questlines.

They will usually give that character a perk, typically making them more effective in combat. They also affect the ending that character gets- most get either a bad ending or no ending narration if you don't complete their quest.